# Converting matlab m file to c file

Tags: c, matlab

I have problem to convert .m file to c class.

I want to make a ccs(code composer studio v6) project which needs a specific matrix, but the matrix is .m file(matlab data).

So, I hope to convert the matrix.m to c class.

for example:  convert 1(.m data) to 2(.cpp data).

1. matlab

   `a = [1, 2 ; 3, 4];`
2. c class

   ```
   class mat{

       public:

           int[2][2]  a;

           void set(){

               a[0][0] =1;

               a[0][1] =2;

               a[1][0] =3;

               a[1][1] = 4;

           }

    }
   ```

In conclusion, my questions are two things.

Firstly, above conversion is possible? Is there any tool? (matrix is too large to convert by hand writing)

Secondly, are there other method to import .m file to ccs?

Thank you.

Comment: A possible way is `fprintf`-ing `a` with the pattern `a[ii][jj] = xxx;` and copy the command window output into your C source file. Another way is storing `a` in a text file and then use `scanf` in C.

Comment: Hello @jms0720, answering for your question: "Secondly, are there other method to import .m file to ccs?" you may found useful this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/). I consider as `.m` file a Matlab function/script that produce your matrix.

Comment: FWIW, this is C++ not C.  C does not have OOP paradigms with the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matlab has extensive support for integration with C.

I would [store the matrix to file](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/save.html),

and then read it using the [C API provided with Matlab](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_external/reading-a-mat-file-in-cc.html).

Or, if you for some reason don't want to use the Matlab API, you can create your own reader based on the [mat file format specification](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf).